# How do I configure my angular library to use the correct install of RxJS llinking it for local testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-library, npm-link

I have been able to build, link and import my library into my main application, however my library provides a service that returns RxJs Observables and I am having an issue where the return type is of the RxJs observable found in the library node_modules, instead of the main application node_modules:

```
Type 'import("D:/KeySystems-Angular-Packages/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'import("d:/KeySystems-WebCustomerPortal/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<boolean>'.
  Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("D:/KeySystems-Angular-Packages/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("d:/KeySystems-WebCustomerPortal/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<any>'.ts(2322)
```

Here is my Angular Library's Workspace's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "key-systems-core-workspace",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/npm": "^2.0.31",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "npm": "^6.12.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^4.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": ">=0.34.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

and the Library project itself:

```
{
  "name": "state-management",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5"
  }
}
```

the library's workspace's tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "state-management": [
        "dist/state-management"
      ],
      "state-management/*": [
        "dist/state-management/*"
      ],
      "rxjs": [
        "./node_modules/rxjs"
      ],
      "rxjs/*": [
        "./node_modules/rxjs/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

my application's tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"],
      "rxjs": [
        "node_modules/rxjs"
      ],
      "rxjs/*": [
        "node_modules/rxjs/*"
      ]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/global-types/typings.d.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true, // allow us to directly import json like modules
    "esModuleInterop": true, // quiets error about default exports when importing json,
    "downlevelIteration": true // supports downleveling iteration to es5 such as Sets
  }
}
```

As I understand it peer dependencies should be in tsconfig path - I assume in the library but that didnt work for me so I tried both as you can see above.

This is a problem because this causes the error:

```
getBusinessClaims(): Observable<IBusinessClaims> {
    return this.stateService.get<IBusinessClaims>(ClaimType.Business);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could change the paths to rxjs in the apps tsconfig to the installation in the node_modules folder from where the package gets rx. Then the rxjs paths would line up again. But I wouldn't advise that for actual builds (you basically don't know what version is there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sounds like the import should be coming from a different location, but in face it was because of a version mixmatch. I imagine it would be a good idea to lock the RxJs package on the minor instead of major in order to avoid this.